# serology of covid 19

Tags: covid-19

Has there been any preliminary serology performed in the outbreak hotspots?

It would be interesting to know if the virus was infact contained or if local herd immunity was achieved by a large part of the population achieving immunity by some not yet identified means

Comment: What's the result of your research?

Comment: Yep, I think a month ago such studies were conducted in Guangdong, and the result was that <0.1% had antibodies. Would need to find out the exact numbers, but it was insignificant from the epidemiological point of view.